# Notepad++ If a line contains a word replace line a certain distance below with a phrase

Tags: notepad++, regex

I'm pretty sure this is possible, and I think it involves Regex, but I have no clue how regex formatting works, and I haven't been able to find the expression I'd need anywhere yet.

Basically I've got a file and want to find every line that contains the word juice and modify the row 10 down and 34 characters in replacing the existing number(almost all start 0.0) with a 1.

Comment: Would be cool if you could provide us an example input and desired output :)

Comment: Yes, it will be possible. Please provide sample data.

Answer (score 1):

I'll start with a small example so that the answer is easier to explain. If your question was to find 3 down and replace 9th character with a '1':

Find what: `(.*juice.*\r\n)(.*\r\n.*\r\n)(.{8})(.)`

Replace with: `$1$2${3}1`

Search Mode: Regular expression

**Explanation**

```
Query:
()   Defines register in regex query. Later to be referenced as ${number}
.*   Defines 0 or more of any character
\r\n Defines a newline
.{8} Defines any character 0 or one time, {8} times
(.)  Defines one character, puts it in its own register 
     In this example, it is register $4, and unused in the replacement

Replace:
$1   Recall register 1 (line containing the word juice)
$2   Recall register 2 (multiple newlines to get us to the third row)
${3} Same meaning as $3, with the "3" in brackets so that it doesn't appear 
     as $31.
$3   Recall register 3 (text before the 9th character)
$4   Contains the contents of register 4. Not recalled, so this text is "replaced" 
     when the full substitution occurs.
1    Literal output the number 1.
```

A literal answer to your question would replace the contents of the `Find what` field with something like the following:

```
(.*juice.*\r\n)(.*\r\n.*\r\n.*\r\n.*\r\n.*\r\n.*\r\n.*\r\n.*\r\n)(.{33})(.)
```

I recommend learning regex. This isn't a NotePad++ specific resource, but it is not so dry as some regex tutorials I have read: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html